# Serialization on the postgresql layer vs. application layer

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, serialization, sequelize.js

I've found surprisingly little information/opinion on this.

Is serialization preferable to happen directly on the sql (in this case postgresql) layer (selecting specific columns) or is it perfectly fine in terms of performance to first fetch the whole record (all columns) and then format the data later in the application layer?

In a NodeJS typescript scenario I'd personally love to serialize on the application layer via simple functional util functions, with certain TS interfaces defining exactly what the final data will look like. This approach would be pretty lightweight and modular in my opinion, however, I'm wondering if there are scenarios where this is not advisable?

Would it matter if we fetch 100 records? Would it matter if perhaps there are 100 columns per row? My understanding is that the main burden for a db is the actual fetching of data, the querying and joining based on complex filters, or does it also make a noticeable difference how many columns you query per record?

To give a graspable code example:

```
const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email }, attributes: ['email', 'username', 'id'] });

// which will be converted to:

SELECT email, username, id FROM users WHERE email = 'some email';
```

vs.

```
const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email } });

// which will be converted to:

SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'some email';

// serialization happens afterwards on the backend app layer

const serializedUser = serializeUser(user);
```

Comment: I removed the <sql> tag since this isn't really related to the SQL _language_. Perhaps you instead should add a tag for the dbms used?

Comment: Hm, despite not being about actual sql code, I still feel like it's strongly about sql given the fact that I'm specifically asking about whether it makes a performance difference for a sql database to query few vs. all fields/columns of a record (or multiple record)?

Edit: Unless the sql tag is exclusively about the sql language as it sounds like you're saying?

Comment: The ANSI/SQL SQL language doesn't deal with implementation, or performance. But your dbms does!

Comment: You're absolutely right, postgresql is the much better fitting tag, thanks

Comment: Two issues 1) Transmitting the data from the database to the front end(client). The less you have to move the better the perceived speed, more so the greater the network distance between the two 2) Security. Transmit to the client only the absolute minimum they need to see or work with. `select * from ...` is security hole.

Comment: I think it has more to do with skills. For a mere 100 records you wouldn't notice the difference, but what about a 100.000 records? Databases are lightning fast, as long as you as a programmer don't make them slow.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, great point, but in my question it is presumed that the app layer (note that I mean the backend app layer) will safely filter out any sensitive attributes that shouldn't be sent to the client. My question is just about whether to do it within the sql query or whether the performance impact is negligible to do it within the backend app layer, in my case javascript/typescript, after having queried the whole record/records from the db with all columns included.

Comment: *... it is presumed that the app layer (note that I mean the backend app layer) will safely filter out any sensitive attributes that shouldn't be sent to the client*. Therein lies the problem and the source of data leaks. If the sensitive data is not present in the app layer it cannot be leaked. All it takes is some backend  developer adding a column with sensitive data and the front end doing `select * from the_table` and the front end developer not getting the memo about the new column and it's nature and then you see said data on the internet.

Comment: As to performance, the only way you can determine that in your situation is through testing, in particular with test cases that cover a reasonable future scenario where there is more data and demand for it.

Comment: Databases like PostgreSQL have a solid permission system, using ACL, GRANT and REVOKE. Why rebuilding something in your own application when you have something that is reliable, is maintained and works? Just because of NIH?

Comment: hm, you're describing a scenario where a select * from query gets sent to the client without any controlled wrapper. In that case you're right, adding a column in the db would mean that column gets automatically included. I was however describing a pattern where each query is wrapped in a controlled way by a serializer with clearly defined types. In general though I like to be explicit within code, so with that being said, your approach does seem cleaner overall.

Comment: There’s index `include` clause. If you select more columns than it has in the index and its payload, it has to get them from the heap. If you only select the indexed field(s) and what’s added as payload through `include`, you get way faster index-only scans. Also, if you cut out a column, you might save an expensive join if all it did was fetch that one thing that the app discards anyways. Views are merged into the query, so skipping the column when selecting from a view could automagically optimise that join away. Columns are also compressed, TOASTed, join tables could be on slower tablespace

Comment: At the end of the day, SQL is declarative: you state what you want and it is the job of the rdbms to figure out the optimal way of delivering that. You are making its job more difficult and then making it your job to then fix/improve/change the result that is flawed because of how you asked for it. “*Tell me everything about everyone in the building (because I want to know the name of the guy next to me)*” - that’d be ridiculous in a hotel but if that’s just three guys in a shed and they only know each other’s names, it’s strange but irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean "project" when you say "serialize".

Database performance is negatively affected if you always fetch all columns instead of only the ones you need. This has several reasons:

- more data has to be transferred across the network
- PostgreSQL has to disassemble ("deform") the whole table rows and cannot stop after the last required column
- PostgreSQL cannot skip de-[toast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html)ing large attributes that are compressed or stored out of line
- PostgreSQL has no chance to eliminate unnecessary joins (if you have any in your queries)